# Core Plot Pie Chart not full when animating

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, core-plot

I have an inconsistent behaviour when animating Pie Chart:
- Full animation
- animation with a little gap at the end.

below is my codes and results!

image link

animation with gap
http://s604.photobucket.com/user/Jcljk/media/IMG_5865_zps83ac73a6.png.html

Full animation
http://s604.photobucket.com/user/Jcljk/media/IMG_5867_zps7beff336.png.html

I appreciate your help.. thank you

```
-(void)configureGraph {

    ///********************** Pie Chart* ***************//////
    // 1 - Create and initialize graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    graph.paddingLeft = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingTop = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingRight = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0f;
    graph.axisSet = nil;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
    // 2 - Set up text style
    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor grayColor];
    textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    textStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    self.selectedTheme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:self.selectedTheme];

        ///********************** End of Pie Chart* ***************//////


}

-(void)configureChart {
    // 1 - Get reference to graph
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    // 2 - Create chart
    CPTPieChart *piePlot = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
    piePlot.dataSource = self;
    piePlot.delegate = self;
    piePlot.pieRadius = (self.hostView.bounds.size.height * 0.7) / 2;

    piePlot.identifier = graph.title;
    piePlot.startAngle = 0;
    piePlot.endAngle = M_PI*2;//2 pi is 1 circle
    piePlot.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
    piePlot.identifier = @"Pie Chart";

    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;

    [CPTAnimation animate:piePlot
                 property:@"startAngle"
                     from:0
                       to:M_PI*2
                 duration:0.5];
  [graph addPlot:piePlot];
}
```

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? I tried this animation in the latest version of the *Plot Gallery* example app and it worked correctly.

Comment: i'm using v1.4. What version is the latest one ? and where can I find the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a + its CorePlotHeaders?

Comment: I also just found out that my app crash when I call configureGraph & configureChart (with different data) if the pie chart hasn't finished animating. your help will be greatly appreciated. I found out that it crash at this point [graph addPlot:piePlot];

Comment: The latest release is 1.5.1 which can be found on [Github](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases).

Comment: Stop all animations on the old graph before you kill it: `[[CPTAnimation sharedInstance] removeAllAnimationOperations];`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the end angle of the pie chart after the animation is finished? I was facing the same problem. What I did was set the end angle in the animationDidFinish method.